# Is there a way to connect my GCP network with a corporate VPN Server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

We have a strict security policy which is based on the usage of our VPN network. I recently joined the company and am trying to strengthen GCP as our new cloud technology.

However the questions I receive are often based on the concern that GCP products like Cloud Run services are "somewhat" in the internet. I tried to convince the team that GCPs security infrastructure is pretty state-of-the-art and there should not be too much concerns for services to be "invaded".

Anyway the core opinion is that the company would like to include the connection/communication to the GCP network into the boundaries of the corporate VPN network.

So my question is - if there is a way to manage this? Does the GCP network has a global IP that I can "whitelist" for the VPN network or what is the approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud, AWS, Azure, etc have very good security features by design. The key is your knowledge of how to implement good security. To answer your question about one global IP - Google Cloud is a global service consisting of millions of services, frontends, endpoints, etc. Using IP addresses as a security vehicle is a horse and buggy in an era of race cars.

Study how authentication and authorization are performed in a [zero trust environment](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/what-zero-trust-identity-security). VPNs are still important but using legacy VPN features will hamper strong security in the cloud.

Security for individual services such as Cloud Run must be considered on a case-by-case basis. Cloud Run is a public service. By adding features, such as serverless connectors, you can configure Cloud Run to be private and accessible only thru your VPN.